# Django update instead of insert a new record

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I having a weird issue with Django 1.3. When I try to add a new Activity using the ActivityForm, the Activity is often updated even if I explicitly create a new Activity object with not Id.

In addition, when the **init** of my ActivityForm class has an explicit trip_id parameter, the UI displays "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." for the field location (even though the selection shown is valid). However, if I make this an optional parameter and I pop it from kwargs, I don't see this issue.

Can someone please take a look at the code below and see what I am doing wrong?

**forms.py**

```
class DestinationMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.city_name

class ActivityForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    location = DestinationChoiceField(queryset = Visit.objects.none(), empty_label=None, required=True)

    def __init__(self, trip_id = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if trip_id is not None:
            self.fields['location'].queryset = Visit.objects.filter(trip=trip_id).all().select_related('destination')

    # A new Activity() is created if nothing is provided
    def save(self, activity = Activity()):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError('ActivityForm was not validated first before trying to call save().')

        activity.visit = self.cleaned_data['location']
        activity.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        activity.added_by = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        activity.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def add_activity(request, trip_id = None, template_name = 'edit-form.html'):
    if request.POST:
        form = ActivityForm(trip_id, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.list_trip'))
    else:
        form = ActivityForm(trip_id)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'page_title': 'Add',
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
def save(self, activity = Activity()):
```

In Python, default parameters are evaluated once; thus, when the `save` method is called *the first time*, a new `Activity` will be created, but subsequent calls will use *that* `Activity`.

Change `save` to something like this:

```
def save(self, activity=None):
    if activity is None:
        activity = Activity()
    # Rest of the method
```

Then, a new `Activity` will be created on every call (if one is not supplied as an argument).

Answer (score 2):

Model instances are mutable. As such they should *never* be used as default arguments to a method, as you do in `save`. There's a reason why you've never seen that in any documentation or examples.

As noted in very many other questions on this site, default arguments are evaluated on definition, not execution. So each call to `save` with no activity argument will use the *same* Activity that was originally defined.

However, I don't understand why you're not using a ModelForm, which does most of this for you in any case.

Comment: I am not using ModelForm because I need to touch multiple entities.